# RxJava 2 Maybe with Observable

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, option-type

I have a simple case i'm trying to do with rxJava 2 but i'm stuck.

I have a locationProvider which returns a Maybe (some model with LatLng). Each time a user clicks on the button, I want to get his current location and save the location to the db.

Just to be clear,
The RxView.clicks(save_btn) should be on the MainThread, the location and db save should be on an async thread, and response should come back to mainThread.

How should I do this?

```
 addDisposeable(RxView.clicks(save_btn)
            .flatMap { locationProvider.getLastKnowLocation().toObservable() }
            .map {
                val place = Place(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "test-address", it.latLng)
                db.placeDao().insertAll(place)
            }
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({
                Toast.makeText(this@AddPlaceActivity, "saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }, { throwable -> Timber.e(throwable) }))
```

I've also tried to simplify it to this:

```
 RxView.clicks(save_btn).share()
                    .flatMap { locationProvider.getLastKnowLocation().toObservable() }
                    .subscribe({
                        val place = Place(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "test-address", it.latLng)
                        db.placeDao().insertAll(place)
                        Timber.d("place-saved")
                    }, { throwable -> Timber.e(throwable) }))
```

But this code only execute for the first click and doesn't continue after.
Is it due to the Maybe.toObservable()? how should it be resolved?
Thanks for your help.

This is the locationProvider's code, i'm using RxLocation:

```
fun getLastKnowLocation(): Maybe<LocationData> {
    return rxLocation.location()
            .lastLocation()
            .map {
                val address = geocoder.getFromLocation(it.latitude, it.longitude, 1).first()
                val latlng = LatLng(it.latitude, it.longitude)
                LocationData(latlng, address)
            }
}
```

Comment: I cannot see anything wrong. Can you show `getLastKnowLocation()` code?

Comment: updated my post @GVillani82

Comment: Then it is hard to say,  but there is something wrong in the library, or at least  it has special use requirements. In order to check if your code is valid, you can simply try replacing that `Maybe` with `return Maybe.just(new LocationData(10,20));` You will see that it will work.

Comment: Have you checked if you get the `onComplete` ? Because it could be related with a null value returned from `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(apiClient);` in [LocationLastMaybeOnSubscribe](https://github.com/patloew/RxLocation/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/patloew/rxlocation/LocationLastMaybeOnSubscribe.java)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately,the user who set me in the correct path deleted his answer :(

This is what I ended up with

```
addDisposeable(
            RxView.clicks(save_btn).share()
                    .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                    .withLatestFrom(locationProvider.getLastKnowLocation().toObservable(), BiFunction { _:Any, l:LocationData -> l })
                    .map {
                        val place = Place(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "test-address", it.latLng)
                        db.placeDao().insertAll(place)
                    }
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe({
                        Timber.d("place-saved")
                    }, { throwable -> Timber.e(throwable) }))
```

I couldn't find a nicer way for the 'BiFunction' part, if anyone has something nicer instead.
Also note that you need to call observeOn twice for the thread switching part.

Comment: Ah! Sorry, I undeleted it.

Comment: don;t know what was the deleted answer, but anyhow I'm not sure `withLatestFrom` will do what you want, it will subscribe only once to the location provider, and will replay the same location for each click - like combineLatest (As the `getLastKnowLocation()` emits only single item by definition - it's a Maybe), you will not get updated location for each user click this way.

Comment: I see your valid point @yosriz, any ideas how to go about it?

Comment: The issue is probably as @GVillani82 comment above, sometimes you'll get null by `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(apiClient)‌` thus your Maybe is completed without any value, why it happened is a separate question but it's not seems related to your stream, anyhow you can use `defaultIfEmpty` to emit default empty value in this case, for handling it at UI level.